# Annotate pointplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

How can I annotate a seaborn pointplot with the values of col1 "A" "B" or "C" as a text, next to the points where they are drawn.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Data
a = list("ABC") * 4
c = list("DE") * 6
score = np.random.randint(-5, 5, 12)
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": a, "col2": c, "score": score})
print(df)

   col1 col2  value
0     A    D      3
1     B    E      1
2     C    D     -3
3     A    E     -5
4     B    D     -4
5     C    E     -5
6     A    D      2
7     B    E     -4
8     C    D      4
9     A    E      1
10    B    D      3
11    C    E     -2

sns.pointplot(data=df, x="col2", y="value", hue='col1');
```

[image: Outcome]

Desired outcome is with the labels A, B and C:

[image: Desired outcome]

Comment: `pointplot` return a matplotlib Axes. You can use its `annotate` or `text` methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.text(x, y, 'a text')` places a text in a plot.  The main problem is to find the exact positions and colors. To get a consistent order, it helps to explicitly make the columns categorical. The categorical numbering (`0, 1, 2, ...`) is the same as matplotlib uses internally for its categorical axes.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

a = list("ABC") * 4
c = list("DE") * 6
score = np.random.randint(-5, 5, 12)
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": a, "col2": c, "score": score})
df['col1'] = pd.Categorical(df['col1'])
df['col2'] = pd.Categorical(df['col2'])

palette = sns.color_palette("tab10")
ax = sns.pointplot(data=df, x="col2", y="score", hue='col1', palette=palette)

pos_after_last_x = len(df['col2'].cat.categories) - 1 + 0.05
last_x_cat = df['col2'].cat.categories[-1]
for cat, color in zip(df['col1'].cat.categories, palette):
    mean_score = df[(df['col1'] == cat) & (df['col2'] == last_x_cat)]['score'].mean()
    ax.text(pos_after_last_x, mean_score, cat, color=color)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]